# worklight build failed due to missing "temp" files of my html

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

I've been running builds successfully for weeks, but the builds started failing this morning.   I tried dropping the WorklightServerHome folder so that the schema would be recreated, but that didn't solve it.   Any ideas?

```
[2013-03-29 09:11:47]             Worklight Server started successfully on localhost:8080
[2013-03-29 09:11:47]             Activating Worklight project: MyFishingReportProject2...
[2013-03-29 09:11:50] FWLSE3005I: Application raw reports are disabled.
[2013-03-29 09:11:50] FWLST0010I: ====== Started server for project MyFishingReportProject2-project-customization; Worklight version=5.0.6.20130311-0918-developer-edition
[2013-03-29 09:11:50]             Activation done.
[2013-03-29 09:11:50]             Starting adapter deployment on Worklight Server
[2013-03-29 09:11:50]             Deploying adapter: FishingReportDB
[2013-03-29 09:11:50]             Server host: localhost
[2013-03-29 09:11:50]             Server port: 8080
[2013-03-29 09:11:51] FWLSE0084I: Deployed adapter 'FishingReportDB' successfully.
[2013-03-29 09:11:51]             Adapter deployed successfully
[2013-03-29 09:11:54]             Activation done.
[2013-03-29 09:11:56]             Starting build process: application 'MyFishingReport', all environments
[2013-03-29 09:11:57] FWLST1040E: common build failed: File 'C:\Users\IBM_AD~1\AppData\Local\Temp\worklightBuildcommon5213198707751472627\preview\default\MyFishingReport.html' does not exist
[2013-03-29 09:11:59] FWLST1040E: mobilewebapp build failed: File 'C:\Users\IBM_AD~1\AppData\Local\Temp\worklightBuildmobilewebapp2958050589803221945\www\default\MyFishingReport.html' does not exist
[2013-03-29 09:12:00] FWLST1040E: android build failed: File 'C:\Users\IBM_AD~1\AppData\Local\Temp\worklightBuildandroid8850935126627789257\www\default\MyFishingReport.html' does not exist
[2013-03-29 09:12:00]             Application 'MyFishingReport' with all environments build finished.
[2013-03-29 09:12:00] FWLST1035I: No environments to build.
```

Comment: Found it...  Somehow, my mouse activity in the outline perspective moved the html file into the js directory...

Comment: Excellent, can you please re-post this as an Answer and marked this question as Answered? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

As the user wrote in a comment, the problem happened due to accidental move operation of the HTML file from its right location (the root of the apps\theApp folder).